# ¿Cómo hacer para utilizar multi tenant para arquitectura saas?

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, ejb

Buenas tares

yo tengo un proyecto en maven el cual tiene la siguiente arquitectura.

```
+ -- Ear
  +-- War
  +-- Ejb
```

En el war se encuentra todo lo relacionado a la web utilizando los frameworks JSF 2.2 y primefaces, por otra parte en el EJB se encuentra las entidades y su respectiva implementación en Session beans, para el manejo de la conexión a base de datos utilizo JPA 2.0 con Hibernate.

La base de datos es postgresql y se encuentran varios esquemas (Tenants).

Por ultimo el servidor de aplicaciones es Glassfish, y alli esta configurado el datasource al cual apunta la unidad de persistencia.

Ahora si despues de la información, no encuentro como hacer que el EJB sepa cual es el usuario que esta haciendo la peticion desde el WAR, y en el EJB como hago para que cambie el schema de acuerdo al usuario.

Encontré varios artículos relacionados, pero todos lo hacen desde un mismo WAR, por lo cual por el request se sabe cual es el usuario que se encuentra logueado, pero ¿Cómo detectarlo en el EJB?

Agradezco su ayuda

Answer (score 1):

**Respecto a la comunicación entre el WAR y el EJB** 
no debe de ser un problema, se me ocurren dos soluciones:

1.- Cuando se loguea un usuario lo guardamos en la sesión, dicho usuario debe contener la información del tenant al que se conecta, y esta información se puede obtener de la sesión desde los EJB sin mayor problema.

2.- Puedes pasar la información del usuario o del tenant como un parámetro cuando el WAR realiza peticiones al EJB. El problema es que dependiendo del tamaño del proyecto puede ser un trabajo tedioso modificar todos los métodos.

**Respecto a que tus EJB cambien la dirección del schema**, [hibernate tiene soporte integrado para sistemas multitenant](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html#d5e4754) por lo que siempre que sea posible intentaría usarlo ya que es confiable y esta probado para la batalla.

Si te decides a usarlo solo tendrias que activarlo e implementar tu propio MultiTenantConnectionProvider con el que le especificas a hibernate que tenant debe usar en cada momento.

**UPDATE**

Ampliando un poco el tema de compartir beans entre distintos módulos de un mismo EAR se me ocurren dos opciones:

1.-JNDI:

Si el bean está registrado mediante JNDI es accesible desde el mismo container sin mayor problema haciendo un lookup:

```
(TenantHolderIF) new InitialContext().lookup("java:global/app/TenantHolder");
```

2.-@Local/@Remote

@Local Esta específicamente pensada para comunicar módulos entre si que pertenecen al mismo EAR, debes crear en tu EJB una interfaz anotada con @Local, esta será la que inyectaras en tu @Interceptor dentro del war, a mi parecer el lugar donde almacenas el valor del último tenant debe ser Statefull o un static.

Aún así no me parece la mejor idea mantener un valor residual con el último tenant y que dependa únicamente de ti y de que añadas los @Interceptor el que un usuario no acceda por error al tenant que había residual. De hecho el mismo Tomas-dovorak aconseja en los comentarios no usar este sistema en un entorno de producción y utilizar los sistemas que brinda hibernate por defecto.

Si aún así decides usar este sistema ten muchísimo cuidado con los Thread y con el valor residual en casos de que se produzca una excepción en alguna parte del flujo de tu aplicación

Un saludo

Comment: Efectivamente todo esta como lo mencionas, actualmente registro la sesión del usuario en un _@Named_ con alcance de _@SessionScope_, ademas tengo implementado la parte en la que selecciona el tenant utilizando el ejemplo de este enlace [JPA Multitenancy] (https://www.tomas-dvorak.cz/posts/jpa-multitenancy/), el problema que no he podido resolver, es pasar los datos del usuario que se encuentra en sesión a los _EJB_, intente realizar mediante un EJB con estado pero al utilizarlo en el _@Interceptor_ no encuentra el valor que asigne anteriormente.

Comment: He ampliado un poco la respuesta con un par de formas de poder compartir objetos dentro del mismo container que es justo lo que necesitas. No entro en muchos detalles de implementación ya que con una simple busqueda en google encontrarás todo lo que necesitas conocer sobre JNDI o las interfaces Local y Remote. Si quieres entrar en detalles de implementación crea otra pregunta con el código en cuestión. Espero haberte ayudado. Un saludo